# R - Knitr script not setting correct WD using opts_knit$set command

Tags: r, knitr

So, I have a directory that is set up as follows:

> Main Directory
>
> > Scripts
> >
> > > RmdOutputs
> >
> > RawData
> >
> > > Dataset1
> > >
> > > Dataset2

And my goal is to create an Rmd document that is capable of reading Raw Data. However, I run into an issue when my Rmd chunks don't seem to recognize the right Working Directory. I originally was running with the setwd() command, but that proved useless in Rmd.

So I googled a bit, and found that there's a separate command option for Rmds about reading WDs for code chunks.

````
```{r load_requirements, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

## Establish Libraries
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

## Set Working Directory
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "C:/MainDirectory")

## Read Data
indata <- read.csv(file.choose())
```
````

This code does not function, and still attempts to pull the WD as my RmdOutputs folder. I'm sorry to ask this as such a crude question, but what have I done wrong so that my script isn't pulling its indata from the correct source?

Comment: If you convert to PDF, and only if you do that, give a try with a standard LaTeX syntax by using `\input{/RawData.Rmd}`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when knitting this document? `file.choose` is an interactive function. And why do you want to change the WD at all? When your WD is `Main Directory/Scripts/RmdOutputs`, just use a relative path to access `RawData`: `../RawData`.